# Play the video will cause Z distortion after rotating on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xorg, intel-graphics, vlc, i915

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the screen display causes Z distortion when playing a video or switching photos quickly after the screen is rotated. [see the recording video](https://youtu.be/wDQqtiqD3wI). I also tried several tests but still no solution, such as testing different monitors, change the different video player(vlc/mpv) or modifying xorg.conf as follows

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "TearFree" "Tree"
EndSection
```

I try to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10, the issue can be solved, but I need to use Ubuntu 20.04 + VLC(VAAPI hwaccel ) because of customer requirement, please help !! thanks.

ENVIRONMENT:

- Display = HDMI/DP
- Resolution = 1920x1080p / 3840x2160
- OS =  Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel 5.11.22
- CPU = Intel TigerLake UP3 , Intel i5-1145 G7E

STEP:

1. System boot up
2. Rotation display to left/right/inverted by `xrandr -o` command
3. Play video using VLC 3.0.9/mpv

RESULT:
screen will cause Z distortion, [see the recording video.](https://youtu.be/wDQqtiqD3wI)